# How can I make a folder in one git repository dependent on another?

Tags: git, github, dependencies

I have two git repositories.  Here is my folder structure

```
~/test/    << This is one project
   .git
   FolderA/
   FolderB/

~/pim/     << This is another project
   .git
   Foo/
   Foo/Bar/
```

The `test` project has the following remote branches

- master
- release1

The `pim` project has the following remote branches

- develop
- master
- release1

I want to create a dependency in the `test` project that maps to a specific folder in the `pim` project.

I want to create something line this:

```
~/test/
   .git
   FolderA/
   FolderB/
   Bar     <<< This maps to the "Foo/Bar" folder in the pim project on branch 

~/pim/
   .git
   Foo/
   Foo/Bar/
```

Here's the pseudo code of what I want to do:
  - In `test`, the `Bar` directory on branch `master` maps to the `Foo/Bar` directory of branch name `release1` in the `pim` project

When a commit happens in the `pim` project, i want the respective folder in `test` to be updated automatically.  The idea is to have `pim` as the main copy where all the code will be submitted.

I looked at [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) and [subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) but they don't appear to help min my case.

Is it possible to achieve this without copying the entire `pim` repo into `test`? What are my options?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an integration server like jenkins or travis-ci, you could clone the last version of your dependant each time you build master repo and trigger a build of master each time the dependant change.
There are also githooks that might be of some interest.